# Add a button at the end of custom list

Tags: java, android, list, button

I'm working on an Android application.
I have created a custom list as follows:

```
private List<Model> getModel()
{

    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>(); //Model is another class

    //Code to populate the list...
}
```

Now I need to add a button at the end of this list. list.addFooterView(mybutton) does not work since it is a custom list and not created via listview.

How do I add a button at the end of the list?

Kindly help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will get more answers if you indicate the language and other details of your environment in your tags.

Comment: Could you clarify, what kind of UI you intend to use? Is it AWT/Swing/SWT or some web application?

Comment: Sorry about that! I'm working on an Android application..

Comment: Why does this matter for this particular question?

Answer (score 0):

If your Button is of a differnt class then Model (which I assume) you can either use an unspecified list like this:

```
List<?> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

then you can add any type of object to it. Of course this way, you loose typesafety and you have to cast the objects yourself. Instead of ? you can also use Object which is the same in this case.

If your Button and Model has a common base class, you can create the list as type of the base class. You still have to cast it though when you need the specific object.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to loose the type safety, you could create a wrapper class.

```
public class MyModel{
    private List<Model> mList;
    private Button mButton;

    public MyModel(List<Model> l, Button b){
        mList = l;
        mButton = b;
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: Even if I create a wrapper class, how do I add a button to the list?

Comment: If the Button really HAS to be in the list, use Devolus's solution. But I don't see a reason why it had to. It all depends on what you want to do with that list afterwards.